# CSP with Nginx & Angular 2 & Material Design - Too much parameters

Tags: angular, nginx, content-security-policy

I'm trying to enable CSP with a Nginx server. My website is an Angular 4 application, and I'm using Material Design to style my application.

I've whitelisted my styles-src using sha256 signatures, but after adding many of the signatures, I get an error: `nginx: [emerg] too long parameter, probably missing terminating """ character in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:142`

Problem is, I have different domain names, and it seems some styles files are loaded for a given domain name, i.e., **the sha signatures differ from one domain name to another**. Moreover, **the styles loaded through angular material are inlined**, and I can't change that since they're included through the AngularMaterial library for Angular 4.

Below is my styles-src I have so far:

```
style-src 'self'
'sha256-ksfuaKuclwdJmmKGPMTnuYiAh2QBugin76nhrWHPvtk='
'sha256-GNDf5DcuZbimJ0vKM649eP69nNOI/5A8E0EWCE5J77g='
'sha256-DQyZACwLM3JY4yTrRNwD33fw5Qx/at+LCEJLMLvk/iE='
'sha256-mNRSDW/8QfKd2RS6R9oshTneUnpNlKPO763tFFufxDQ='
'sha256-+ZuFEYSrp+j56kFDHaHP/gVpiyPb00t/Tf0EdkqJYM0='
...
```

Is there any way to make one signature global to each domain name, so I don't have to whitelist the same file for each domain name?
I know I can use the `unsafe-inline` parameter, but this is kind of risky and loses the win of using CSP.

Comment: Given that the relevant limit in nginx for this is 4096 bytes, it seems like you must have something on the order 70 or more sha256 signatures you’re adding to the Content-Security-Policy header value you’re trying to set in your nginx config file. Is that the case?

Comment: It’s not clear from your question, but by *“I have different domain names”*, it sounds like what you mean in nginx terms is that you have multiple virtual servers (`server` blocks) each with a different `server_name` and that (I guess) the way you have your nginx config set up is that you’re using one single `add_header Content-Security-Policy` directive to send the same `Content-Security-Policy` header across all the virtual servers. Is that the case? If so, why not instead have multiple separate `add_header Content-Security-Policy` directives, one for each `server` block (`server_name`)?

Comment: @sideshowbarker yes that's the case, I have a huge bunch of sha256 signatures due to the stylesheets Angular Material2 generates at runtime.
What I meant is, it seems Angular Material2 generates some files that differ from one domain name to another, i.e., let's say I whitelisted the stylesheets for example.com, then when accessing my application through example.com, I have no problem with the CSP. However, if I access my application through example.org, some stylesheets are blocked by CSP.